# Spring defining get multiple entity manager for same datasource

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, datasource, entitymanager

Is it possible to define multiple `EntityManager` on same `datasource` in Spring?

Comment: Sure. Why do you think that does not work? http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-setup-multiple-data-sources-with-spring-and-jpa/ Just try it.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Thanks :)